# Taipei tourist shuttle bus - where do they depart and when?

Tags: buses, taipei

It says there are [Taiwan Tourist Shuttles](https://Taiwan%20Tourist%20Shuttle) in Taipei but cannot find the details where they depart and their time tables. Resources just explains what they are and [Taiwan Tourist Shuttle website](https://www.taiwantrip.com.tw/) does not work and gives no information.

Any good information source?

Comment: [The website you list has timetable information](https://www.taiwantrip.com.tw/Frontend) although the form doesn't work terribly well. It requires you to select start, destination, route, date, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The departure stops and timetables are actually available on the Taiwan Tourist Shuttle website; see, e.g. [this page for the S9 Beitou Zhuzihu Route](https://www.taiwantrip.com.tw/Frontend/Route/Select_p?RouteID=R0022). Unfortunately, the website's navigation is not the most friendly for English-speaking visitors -- clicking "English" on the top navigational bar will send you back to the homepage.

If you know roughly where you are starting and going, as @Stuart F pointed out, you can use the Timetable & Fare search function right below website's banner image. Searching for locations on Taiwanese websites often requires you to specify the city/county first. Given that you have tagged [taipei](/questions/tagged/taipei) in your question, you are likely looking for the top four options -- Taipei, New Taipei, Taoyuan, and Keelung (perhaps also Yilan, which is near the bottom).

If you are looking for inspiration, scroll further down on the homepage until you hit the "Routes" section. On the left (top on mobile) is an interactive by-city/county map of Taiwan, and on the right (bottom on mobile) is a panel showing a menu of routes under each city/county. By default, it shows cities/counties in northern Taiwan, those close to Taipei. To look for routes in other regions, click on the coloured blocks on the left.

[image: Routes section on the Taiwan Tourist Shuttle website, showing a interactive by-county map of Taiwan on the left and a panel listing the cities/counties and bus routes.]

Clicking "More >" under each route will lead you to another page introducing the route. The page also has a button linking to the timetable and bus fare chart.

---

That said, where these routes are geared towards tourists, they are quite similar to other local buses (in terms of actual route taken or fare), and thus, you should not rule the local buses out when you plan your travel.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I bought Taipei Fun Pass and its explanation says it includes five Taiwan Tourist Shuttle routes, hence looking for where they depart from within Taipei as the Pass is only available in Taipei. Now I start getting the sense, but really difficult to understand how to use them.

Comment: @mon Right, I see. The Taipei metropolitan area covers the jurisdiction of multiple cities/counties and so don't be put off if the start of a certain route is purportedly not in Taipei City boundaries. All local buses in New Taipei and Keelung are covered. Ruifang, [where you can get on a route covered by the pass](https://taipei.funpass.app/theme/taipeifunpass_abroad/images/download/map_en.jpg), is a short (and affordable) train ride away.